# Find the $\mathbb{E}[ W_{t} ^ {3} e^{W_1-\frac{1}{2}}]$

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

i am trying to compute  the $$\mathbb{E}[  W_{t} ^ {3}  e^{W_1-\frac{1}{2}}]$$

where $(W_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a standard Brownian Motion.

Any idea would be appreciated, thanks in advance !

Comment: What have you tried so far? Itô's formula? Independent Increments (which gets messy, I know :D)

Comment: is it $\mathbb{E}[  W_{t} ^ {3}  e^{W_t-\frac{1}{2}}]$ or $\mathbb{E}[  W_{t} ^ {3}  e^{W_1-\frac{1}{2}}]$ ?

Comment: to be honest i have tried to take two cases for t>1 and t<1 and try to calculate the conditional expectation to the sigma algebra $F_1$ and then $F_t$ using the independent increments but with no luck @Stockfish

Comment: its $W_1$   $\mathbb{E}[ W_{t} ^ {3} e^{W_1-\frac{1}{2}}]$  @Khosrotash

Comment: @Soer what about t=1? Did you solve that one?

Comment: And maybe try to use $W_t^3 = (W_t-W_1+W_1)^3 = (W_t - W_1)^3 + 3(W_t-W_1)^2W_1+3(W_t-W_1)W_1^2+W_1^3$